# Multiple Google play developer account

Tags: android, google-play, account, suspend

I have a google developer account with 2 suspend, the third suspend mean banned of my account , now i want to create a new account developer to work with , my question is if i published app in my new account and get a suspend, Will this suspend be counted on the first account as well ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not be counted.
it will only count for the second account!

Comment: Can someone confirm this please?
And if it is the case, can this 2nd account just have the same credit card.